# eso - How much dmg does burning do

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO any fire dmg has a chance to apply burning. I found tens of post on how it is applied, how it stacks, how it refreshes. Also most skills explain pretty clear the things listed before.

What I fail to find anywhere is HOW MUCH DMG IT MAKES. Not in the skill tooltips, not in posts, not anywhere.

So I'm assuming the dmg made by burning is fixed and independent on source / spellpower / magika / buffs / etc. (if it was it should've been listed on skills tooltip). Still... how much is it?

Comment: Do you have damage indicators turned on? Then you can see how much damage you do on your enemies(can't remember where, probably interface)

Comment: Afaik that is an addon. I am using ftc and can see total dmg done by burning, but since I don't know exactly when during the fight burning started and ended can't know the exact duration so the exact dps. I will download and turn on an addon to display dmg each time it happens but hoped I won't need to do that especially to find out burning dps.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion about how burning works,and it has also changed a couple of times over the course of the game. I can weirdly enough not find any information online about whether it scales with certain numbers or not. Does Bethesda have some kind of embargo on that stuff?

Comment: @Nzall Trust me... I searched for hours before posting this. Having an embargo on this would be stupid since everything else is public. Also they provide apis for LUA addons. I think that ppl just didn't ask :).